# How to write a text file after the previous line in C#?

Tags: c#, io, append

My below code creates a txt file and writes something to that file. But I need to write a new line after the previous lines when I run the script several times. Code:

```
string filePath = "D:\\DOT_NET\\C#\\abc.txt";
FileInfo t = new FileInfo(filePath);
StreamWriter Tex = t.CreateText();
Tex.WriteLine("Hi freinds");
Tex.WriteLine("csharpfriends is the new url for c-sharp");
Tex.Write(Tex.NewLine);
Tex.Close();
```

Current output on the `abc.txt` file:

```
Hi friends
csharpfriends is the new url for c-sharp
```

But I need the output if I run the script several times to be this:

```
Hi friends
csharpfriends is the new url for c-sharp

Hi friends
csharpfriends is the new url for c-sharp

Hi friends
csharpfriends is the new url for c-sharp
```

How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: First of all, I think you should put the StreamWriter declaration inside an using block.

Answer (score 6):

StreamWriter has a constructor which lets you append text instead of just writing into the file. The constructor is

```
new StreamWriter(string filepath, bool append)
```

If you set that bool to "true", then all writing will be at the end of the document. In your example...

```
StreamWriter Tex = new StreamWriter(@"D:\DOT_NET\C#\abc.txt", true);
```

Comment: thanks for ans,but it will be better for me if you pls elaborate your ans.pls guide how can i add the constractor on my mentioned code..

thanks
riad

Comment: @riad Replace your current StreamWriter Tex declaration with the one I wrote below. You don't have to change anything else since you still close it properly.

Comment: What is there to elaborate? What *exactly* isn't clear in @ccomet's answer?

Comment: I don't think ccomet is a 'bro'.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
{
   sw.WriteLine("...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"file_location", System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"file_location") + System.Environment.NewLine + "The_new_text");
```

That will add a new text to the next line.